# How to send user_id to Google Analytics 4 when use vue-gtag, nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, google-analytics, nuxt.js

I have a project with Nuxtjs.
I'm using https://github.com/MatteoGabriele/vue-gtag. I tried to send user_id to Google Analytics 4 when id of user exists with code blow but not working. I have checked in GA4 but not has data "Signed in with user ID includes yes":

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueGtag from "vue-gtag";

export default ({ $config, $auth }) => {
  const obj = {
    config: {
      id: 'G-XXXXXXXXXX'
    }
  }
  if ($auth?.loggedIn) {
    obj.config.params = {user_id: $auth.user.sub}
  }
  Vue.use(VueGtag, obj, app.router)
}
```

Code below is working:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueGtag from "vue-gtag";

export default ({ $config, $auth }) => {
  Vue.use(VueGtag, {
    config: {
      id: 'G-XXXXXXXXXX',
      params: {
        user_id: '122xzczxc'
      }
    }
  }, app.router)
}
```

Can i help you? I want to send user_id to GA4 when user_id exists.

Comment: I thinks what is not working is your user is never loggedIn ?
Put a log above the condition with `console.log($auth?.loggedIn)`. I'm pretty sur is always false, and that's the problem. If it's not the case do the same with `$auth.user.sub`

Comment: @RaphaelRollet i put log `console.log($auth?.loggedIn)` then i login. This code return true and `$auth.user.sub` have value.

Comment: That a good news but weird.
If you say with the static code you got the user_id it's GA4 works nicely.
You need to do some test, add inside the obj this: `params: { user_id: '123-default-id' }` and in your `obj.config.params` change the value of user_id by `'123-update-id'`, what you got ?

Comment: @RaphaelRollet if i added only in `obj.config.params` but not working. Add inside the obj this: `params: { user_id: '123-default-id' }` and in my `obj.config.params ` is working with login or not.

Answer (score 0):

To respond properly after the comment and what i think i have understand.

If you change your conditional by a default value like:

```js
if ($auth?.loggedIn) {
  obj.config.params = {user_id: '123-update-id'}
}
```

This not works.

But if you initialize your object like that:

```js
const obj = {
  config: {
    {
      id: 'G-XXXXXXXXXX',
      params: {
      user_id: '123-default-id'
    }
  }
}
```

The condition on `$auth?.loggedIn` will works and assign the value.

In that case the problem is just you need to have a default structure for your object. In this case the object not create a new property who can cause async or structure problem, it just update a property.

Just do that:

```js
const obj = {
  config: {
    {
      id: 'G-XXXXXXXXXX',
      params: {
      user_id: ''
    }
  }
}
```